# Flutter Web Navigator/Overlay layout issue

Tags: flutter-layout, overlay, flutter-web

When I started my first flutter web business application my goal was to place the MaterialApp navigator just inside the place where I want all pages to be loaded. Therefore I used the MaterialApp builder to accomplish that. This builder gives me the context and navigator and I can return the widget tree I desire.

Everything was great, I created and returned a widget tree that looked like the code below:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(),
  body: Row(children: [
    MySideBar(),
    Expanded(
      child: navigatorFromTheMaterialAppBuider,
    ),
  ]),
)
```

By doing this way I have a fixed sidebar and appbar, and all pages are loaded without any rebuild on the fixed part.

The problem began when I needed to place some widgets that depends on the Overlay class inside my sidebar. Because sidebar is outside the MaterialApp navigator an overlay can't be found. Another side effect of doing this kind of layout was that any widget placed inside my pages and therefore inside the navigator displayed its overlay entries with the exact offset of the sidebar width and appbar height.

To avoid change that layout structure and make appbar and sidebar part of every page of my web application, I'd like to know if there is a way of placing an Overlay above the navigator (or even above the MaterialApp widget) that can override the MaterialApp navigator overlay for the entire tree of widgets.

I created a dartpad sample code to make it clearer.
https://dartpad.dev/140e1e8a9ca0620301b43d0313e20bdb

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66870

This seems to have been fixed by a recent PR